# Toggle Switch unable to maintain the set value when onClicked

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want a toggle switch when onClicked would set thew current boolean value to its opposite. When the toggle button is clicked it sets to false but reverts back to true. I added a event.preventDefault to stop the refresh; however, though im getting the correct set value and stopped it from reverting back to default state when onClicked, the toggle no longer toggles left to right.

```
function CreateForm() {
    const [isPrivate, setPrivate] = useState(true);


    const handleStatus = (event) => {
        // event.preventDefault();
        setPrivate(!isPrivate)
        console.log(isPrivate)
    }
    return (
                    <div className='createform__switch'>
                        <h5 className='createform__private'>Private</h5>
                        <label className="switch" htmlFor="checkbox"  onClick={handleStatus}>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
                            <div className="slider round"></div>
                        </label>
                        <h5 className='createform__public'>Public</h5>
                    </div>

      )
}
```

how can I stop the value from reverting back to its default state but at the same time have a functioning animated toggle switch.

please, any help will be great

Comment: would it not be adding a checked attribute that is set to the isPrivate boolean ?  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked={isPrivate} />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the checkbox you are calling the `handleStatus` method which changes the `isPrivate` value and then you are logging the value in the console. The thing is, that the `isPrivate` state is not been updated until the method execution is finished, so you are seeing the previous value in the console.

So the `handleStatus` method will look like this:

```js
const [isPrivate, setPrivate] = useState(true);

const handleStatus = () => {
    setPrivate(!isPrivate)
    console.log(!isPrivate)
}
```

I also leave you some fixes of the code:

```
<div className='createform__switch'>
    <h5 className='createform__private' style={{fontWeight: isPrivate ? "bolder" : "lighter"}}>Private</h5> 
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" checked={isPrivate} onChange={handleStatus} />
    <h5 className='createform__public' style={{fontWeight: isPrivate ? "lighter" : "bolder"}}>Public</h5>
</div>
```